# Q: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/document/image:35: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am in the process of selecting several images and send them to the server.
Get the image uri array from the main and process it in the viewModel.

```
private fun changeType(imageUriList: ArrayList<Uri>): ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> {
    var imageRequestList = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()
    
    for(i in 0 until imageUriList.size) {
        val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(path, imageUriList[i].path.toString())
        try {
            if (!path.isDirectory) {
                path.mkdirs()
            }
            file.createNewFile()
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val requestFile = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
        val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, requestFile)
        imageRequestList.add(body)
    }

    return imageRequestList
}
```

this is viewModel

```
E/WritingViewModel: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/document/image:35: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

error message

Comment: File names cannot contain ':' chars. Forbidden.

Comment: You should use these uries directly. No need mesing around with uri paths and external storage. That code makes no sense.